# How to avoid numerous Hyperparameter tuning in ML?

Tags: machine-learning, hyperparameter-tuning

Suppose I have developed a dynamic system for forecasting the future of some specific stocks. As time passes, the train set will change dynamically. For a better understanding, consider this example:

- **First Round:**
  train set = [0 : 150] (The first 150 samples are in the training set)
  test set = [150 : 152]
- **Second Round:**
  train set = [1 : 151]
  test set = [151 : 153]
- **Third Round:**
  train set = [2 : 152] (152 is exclusive)
  test set = [152 : 154]
- and so on.

For each round, I use a [`RandomSearchCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) to tune hyperparameters of [`Random Forest`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html?highlight=randomforest#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor) to predict the returns of some stocks using specific features. I am focusing on tuning hyperparameters in this question.

As I mentioned, I perform a Hyperparameter tuning in each round, **which costs a lot of time! (specifically when the train set is enormous)** So I'm seeking a way to avoid This hyperparameter tuning each round repeatedly. I'm interested to know, How scientists perform hyperparameter tuning (considering time-consuming process)?
Shall I perform hyperparameter tuning just once and precisely before the first round?

Answer (score 1):

A good hyperparameter may be considered as a random variable with some variation. I wouldn't worry to much not to find the best parameter for one specific test set. In case you are sure there should be multiple values for some parameter, I would try to do it not for all test sets but with some step. Please take into account, cross validation "contaminates" your assessment. You'll definitely get more optimistic metric score on data you used for cv.

Imagine, you have 100 test n folds. You may use the first 10 of them for cv, then assess the next 10 test n folds with the best model and hyperparameter you got on the previous step. These 10 folds will give you more realistic score. Then repeat the bundle (10 cv folds + 10 assessment folds).

Also, if you really use test set with size 2, your estimates for the hyperparameter may vary too much. You may compare it with bigger test fold size.

Answer (score 0):

Automated hyper-parameter tuning could be done through a genetic algorithm like [PyGAD](https://pygad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). It will explore plenty of random scenarios automatically and get the best one.

In addition to that, you are not forced to apply the learning process completely: most learning processes are quite the same after a few iterations or processing steps.

You can look for optimizing the first iterations/steps, which takes less time, and then check if the hyperparameters are actually better by testing a few complete processes scenarios.

Finally, computation power is also crucial and you can use cloud services like [Paperspace](https://www.paperspace.com/) to process your function with powerful GPUs like an RTX5000.